# I have to open windows fonts folder after install my application by installaware

Tags: delphi, fonts, directory, installaware

I've built a installer by installaware for my application. I'm copying some fonts to windows fonts folder automatically during the installation. When I open the installed application, fonts doesn't displayed correctly until I open and close windows fonts folder or restart the computer. Is there any solution to enable me not need to open fonts folder or restart computer? something like refresh windows newly installed fonts.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

The required procedure is [described over at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144833.aspx). To summarise:

- Copy the font to the %windir%\fonts folder.
- Call [`AddFontResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183326.aspx) or [`AddFontResourceEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183327.aspx).
- Broadcast the [`WM_FONTCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145211.aspx) message to all top-level windows.

It may be easier to find a way to persuade your installer tool to do this work for you.